# Python program with menu option and restricted input accepted

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to make a program like that but I am stuck at one point.Any help is welcome.Thanks

MENU OPTION
1-  Calculate bat average
2-  Exit program

Menu option : (input user)
Calculate batting average…
Number at bats: (int input)
Number hits: (int input)
Batting average: (average at bats,hits)

Menu option: 1
Calculate batting average…
Number at bats: 20000000
=>invalid number. Must be from 0 to 1000
Number at bats: 14
Number hits: 15
=>error, hits cannot be greater than at bats

Menu option:3
=> Invalid entry

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your existing code so we can assist you better. In addition, please read [mcve].

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried?

Comment: how do you do that ?